# Split multidimensional array into arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I have a result from a form post that looks like this:

```
$data = [
    'id_1' => [ 
        '0' => 1,
        '1' => 2
     ],
    'id_2' => [ 
        '0' => 3,
        '1' => 4
    ],
    'id_3' => [ 
        '0' => 5,
        '1' => 6
    ]
];
```

What I want to achieve is to split this array into two different arrays like this:

```
$item_1 = [
    'id_1' => 1,
    'id_2' => 3,
    'id_3' => 5
]

$item_2 = [
    'id_1' => 2,
    'id_2' => 4,
    'id_3' => 6
]
```

I've tried using all of the proper array methods such as array_chunk, array_merge with loops but I can't seem to get my mind wrapped around how to achieve this. I've seen a lot of similar posts where the first keys doesn't have names like my array does (id_1, id_2, id_3). But in my case the names of the keys are crucial since they need to be set as the names of the keys in the individual arrays.

Comment: [array_column](http://php.net/array_column) _might_ be of use, though potentially not if you need the keys. A simple foreach might be the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much shorter than this will be hard to find:

```
$item1 = array_map('reset', $data);
$item2 = array_map('end', $data);
```

#### Explanation

[`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) expects a callback function as its first argument. In the first line this is [`reset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php), so `reset` will be called on every element of `$data`, effectively taking the first element values of the sub arrays. `array_map` combines these results in a new array, keeping the original keys.

The second line does the same, but with the function [`end`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php), which effectively grabs the last element's values of the sub-arrays.

The fact that both `reset` and `end` move the internal array pointer, is of no concern. The only thing that matters here is that they also return the value of the element where they put that pointer to.

Answer (score 0):

Solution without loop and just for fun:

```
$result = [[], []];
$keys = array_keys($data);
array_map(function($item) use(&$result, &$keys) {
    $key = array_shift($keys);
    $result[0][$key] = $item[0];
    $result[1][$key] = $item[1];
}, $data);
```

Comment: Why not `array_walk` if you're going to throw out the result?

Comment: @Jon array_map and array_walk have different purposes. I don't want to modify existing array as array_walk does. I want to generate a new one with completely different structure.

Comment: `array_walk` doesn't do anything except loop. `array_map` loops *and* constructs an array to return. In general, `array_map` and `array_walk` are equivalent in the same sense that `for` and `while` are equivalent: anything you can write using one, you can also write using the other. Of course each is intended to be used in different situations, and `array_map` is not intended to be used like this. You are not bothering to return anything from the callback, so PHP builds an array of nulls that it then throws away (you don't save the return value). Which is my point.

Answer (score 0):

Just a normal `foreach` loop will do.

```
$item_1 = [];
$item_2 = [];
foreach ($data as $k => $v){
    $item_1[$k] = $v[0];
    $item_2[$k] = $v[1];
}
```

Hope this helps.